# Can C# dataflow blocks possess a state?

Tags: c#, multithreading, tpl-dataflow

I'm learning C# TPL Dataflow and have familiarized myself with some of the basic blocks. However, I'm starting to wonder how to configure more advanced blocks for my application.

For example, let's say I have an action block that receives integers and writes them to a database. When I configure this action block, it seems like I just give it a stateless function to perform whenever it receives data.

However, it seems like this block should be in charge of establishing and monitoring the database connection which consequently causes the dataflow block to possess a state.

Furthermore, let's say I want this action block to feature a "scaling" property where it can scale the data before writing to the database. I also want this scaling property to be adjustable such that someone can change the scale factor on the fly.

In both of these cases, it seems like the action block requires knowledge of some state.

What is the typical procedure for building data flow blocks that possess state?

Comment: When doing Multitasking with a DB, I leave the concurrency to the Database. I also have a standing advise to not keep a Database connection open. Create, Use, Dispose. All in the same piece of code, ideall using a using block. In that case, there is nothing to watch over.

Comment: @Christopher there's a difference between TPL and DB *best* practices....

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ The actuall DB is going to be the bottleneck either way. It is designed to be the bottleneck. Moving the Bottlenecking/Concurrency away from it is going to cause issues. Splitting up the creation and disposing of the connection is going to cause issues. And multitasking is *already* so hard, you want to avoid any additional issues. | No mater how sophisticated you get, it is very important to never forget the mistakes of the beginners.

Comment: @Izzo what does `scale the data before writing to the database` mean? In any case, you don't really need state or a persistent connection *all that much*. The fastest way to insert data into a database is to use its bulk import mechanisms, like SQL Server's `BULK INSERT` or `SqlBulkCopy`. Depending on the number of rows you use, you can use a `BatchBlock` to batch rows into eg 5K row batches and use an `ActionBlock` at the end that opens a connection and uses `SqlBulkCopy` to write it all out.

Comment: @Izzo SQL Servers SSIS *Dataflows* work that way too. Each step is a separate block. Transformations pull data from the input buffer, process it and send it to the output buffer. Some of them cache data, some don't. SSIS uses a single connection per destination though, while a (not so) naive implementation with ActionBlock will open a new one - which is actually free due to connection pooling.

Comment: I've answered a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60620852/can-an-actionblock-contain-a-state/60645023#60645023