# Can an ActionBlock contain a state?

Tags: c#, lambda, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I'm writing an application that is using TPL dataflow. I'm trying to configure an action block to write to a database.

However, I need this action block to perform an initialization step on the first message it receives (note that I must wait for the first message and cannot perform the initialization during the action block creation).

Because of this, my action block needs to maintain some sort of state that indicates if its already received the first message.

Is it possible for an ActionBlock to maintain a state?

Referencing the Microsoft sample code below, how would I go about adding a state variable to the ActionBlock? It seems like it only maintains local variables.

```
// Performs several computations by using dataflow and returns the elapsed
// time required to perform the computations.
static TimeSpan TimeDataflowComputations(int maxDegreeOfParallelism,
   int messageCount)
{
   // Create an ActionBlock<int> that performs some work.
   var workerBlock = new ActionBlock<int>(
      // Simulate work by suspending the current thread.
      millisecondsTimeout => Thread.Sleep(millisecondsTimeout),
      // Specify a maximum degree of parallelism.
      new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
      {
         MaxDegreeOfParallelism = maxDegreeOfParallelism
      });

   // Compute the time that it takes for several messages to 
   // flow through the dataflow block.

   Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
   stopwatch.Start();

   for (int i = 0; i < messageCount; i++)
   {
      workerBlock.Post(1000);
   }
   workerBlock.Complete();

   // Wait for all messages to propagate through the network.
   workerBlock.Completion.Wait();

   // Stop the timer and return the elapsed number of milliseconds.
   stopwatch.Stop();
   return stopwatch.Elapsed;
}
```

Comment: Is the `ActionBlock` configured with `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` greater than one? If yes, what should happen during the first messages that will be processed in parallel? Should all threads wait for the initialization step to complete before continuing?

Comment: What is the reason that you cannot initialize before you kick the work off?

Comment: @VictorWilson I need to save the first timestamp received. This is only known once the first message is received (not during object construction).

Comment: Why not just pass a count in the data of the incoming posts? Act only if it is zero?

Comment: @spender I was going to suggest the same thing, but I wasn't sure if the initialization action should be completed before further messages can be processed. It seems that the "initialization" is just saving a timestamp somewhere, which makes your suggestion quite sufficient for the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could implement your own `StatefulActionBlock<T>`, like so.  Depending on your `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` you may not need the lock (and even if you do there may be better ways of achieving thread-safety). Thanks to @TheodorZoulias for helping me refine this approach.

```
public class StatefulActionBlock<TInput, TState> : IDataflowBlock, ITargetBlock<TInput>
{
   private bool _initialized;

   private Action<TState> _initializer;

   private object _lock = new object();

   private ITargetBlock<TInput> _actionBlock;

   private TState _state;

   public Task Completion => _actionBlock.Completion;

   public StatefulActionBlock(Action<TInput> action, Action<TState> initializer, TState state, ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions options)
   {
       //null checks omitted...

       _initializer = initializer;
       _actionBlock = new ActionBlock<TInput>(action, options);
       _state = state;
   }

   void Initialize()
   {
       _initializer(_state);
       _initialized = true;
   }

   public DataflowMessageStatus OfferMessage(DataflowMessageHeader messageHeader, TInput messageValue, ISourceBlock<TInput> source, bool consumeToAccept) 
   {
       lock (_lock)
       {
           if (!_initialized)
               Initialize();
       }
       return _actionBlock.OfferMessage(messageHeader, messageValue, source, consumeToAccept);
   }

   public void Complete() =>
       _actionBlock.Complete();

   public void Fault(Exception exception) =>
       _actionBlock.Fault(exception);
}
```

---

You could also lock and check to see if you're initialized in your Action.

```
private static object _lock = new Object();
private static bool _isInitialized = false;

// Performs several computations by using dataflow and returns the elapsed
// time required to perform the computations.
static TimeSpan TimeDataflowComputations(int maxDegreeOfParallelism, int messageCount)
{
   // Create an ActionBlock<int> that performs some work.
   var workerBlock = new ActionBlock<int>(
      // Simulate work by suspending the current thread.
      DoStuff,
      // Specify a maximum degree of parallelism.
      new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
      {
         MaxDegreeOfParallelism = maxDegreeOfParallelism
      });

   // Compute the time that it takes for several messages to 
   // flow through the dataflow block.

   Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
   stopwatch.Start();

   for (int i = 0; i < messageCount; i++)
   {
      workerBlock.Post(1000);
   }
   workerBlock.Complete();

   // Wait for all messages to propagate through the network.
   workerBlock.Completion.Wait();

   // Stop the timer and return the elapsed number of milliseconds.
   stopwatch.Stop();
   return stopwatch.Elapsed;
}

private static void DoStuff(int i)
{
    lock (_lock)
    {
       if (!_initialized)
       {
          Initialize();
          _initialized = true;
       }
    }
    Thread.Sleep(i); //make a snack
}

private static void Initialize()
{
   //...
}
```

Comment: About the `StatefulActionBlock` implementation, the initialization check will be probably bypassed if the block is linked as a receiver of another block. I suggest that you remove the `Post` and `SendAsync` methods, and move the initialization check inside the `OfferMessage` method. Also having a generic class with a specific hardcoded `Initialize` implementation somewhat defeats the point of reusability. Couldn't you make it an argument passed in the constructor?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I like it.  Thank you.  I've made an edit.

Comment: I've never done this in practice; I'm not sure how the OfferMessage behaves, and Mr Izzo is using Post directly, so I've left that in my implementation.

Comment: There are generic extension `Post` and `SendAsync` methods in the static [`DataflowBlock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblock) class, that probably propagate the messages via the `OfferMessage` of the target block. But I may be wrong.

Comment: Yeap, I just checked the source code of `DataflowBlock.Post` [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/e99ec129cfd594d53f4390bf97d1d736cff6f860/src/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow/src/Base/DataflowBlock.cs#L246), and it is straightforward. The source code of `DataflowBlock.SendAsync` is quite complex though.